# What steps can I take to diagnose the lack of response when trying to upload an image through Postman in my Cloudinary-Express API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, cloudinary

i am building a backend nodejs/express api to upload image files to cloudinary.i am encountering an error while testing this in postman
here is the backend code

```
app.post(
  '/api/upload/:id',
  asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const file = req.body.data
      const uploadResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
        file.tempFilePath,
        {
          folder: 'profile',
          upload_preset: 'my_media',
          use_filename: true,
        }
      )
      console.log(uploadResponse)
      const { secure_url } = uploadResponse
      const newUser = await userModal.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        image: secure_url,
      })
      newUser.image = secure_url
      res.status(201).json(newUser)
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).json(error)
    }
  })
)
```

this is the code for upload api
[postman testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRVJj.png)
this is how i test it with postman
but here i am not able to log this file to console and the end point is not working

i have tried to upload image to cloudinary via nodejs express api.
i want to upload image through postman
but getting no response

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and it should output the error:

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(
  file.tempFilePath,
    {
      folder: 'profile',
      upload_preset: 'my_media',
      use_filename: true,
    }
)
.then(uploadResult => console.log(JSON.stringify(uploadResult, null, 2)))
.catch(error => console.error("error: ", error));
```